# Why are commands reading from /dev/stdin get a status "[1]+ Stopped" when sent to background?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, cat, stdin, jobs

I have tried running the following commands:

- `cat`
- `base64 /dev/stdin`
- `md5sum /dev/stdin`
- `tail /dev/stdin`

In all cases when I do:

```
^Z
$ bg
$ jobs
```

I get the status: `[1]+  Stopped` instead of `[1]+  Running`.

But if I read from a pipe then the job is considered running:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo1

cat /tmp/fifo1
^Z
$ bg
$ jobs

# [1]+  Running                 tail /tmp/fifo1 &
```

Why reading from `/dev/stdin` makes a command to be considered as `Stopped` when sent to background?

Comment: What do you think should happen if the background process and the foreground process both try to read the same _stdin_?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design; it is how POSIX job control is designed.

Under POSIX job control, there is a TTY device (the "controlling TTY") which is associated with multiple jobs (represented by processes placed into a process groups).  One process group at a time is the foreground process group; the others are background process groups.

When a process in a background process group tries to read from the controlling terminal, it gets a `SIGTTIN` signal, and is stopped.

It's also possible for a background process group to receive a `SIGTTOU` when it tries to **write** to the terminal. There is a TTY flag which controls whether this behavior is enforced: i.e. whether writes from the background are allowed or not. (The command interface to set or clear that flag is `stty tostop`/`stty -tostop`).

The purpose of this is that it would be a crazy mess if background processes could steal your TTY input. Your keystrokes would be randomly distributed among the background processes. POSIX job control not only juggles processes, but acts like a traffic cop for TTY input (and possibly output) to prevent confusion.